# CSS - Space after "|" when added with after

Tags: css

I have a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/3sph9wpg/5/

Super simple I have a list with display:inline; to create a horizontal nav

I want a bar between each element which I can add with after

My problem is I seem to have a space after the bar that I cant remove

I need to add a space inside the

which I don't like doing

```
    ul{
        list-style: none;

        li{
            display: inline-block;

            &:after{
                content: "|";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not related to the `::after` - it's because `display: inline-block` causes the white space between nodes (i.e. between one closing tag and the next opening tag) to be parsed as a single space.

There's several ways round this. Since the size of the added space is dictated by the inherited font size, one approach is to set a font size of 0 on the parent `ul`.

CSS:

```
ul { font-size: 0; }
```

Output:

```
one|two|three
```

No whitespace will now show between the nodes. However, this can cause problems of the LIs have a relative font size set in ems. Using pixels or rem's gets round this problem.

[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/rw0as2uL/)

Another approach is to use floats rather than inline-block, which doesn't suffer from this problem.

```
li { float: left; }
```

[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/rw0as2uL/1/)

Comment: Possible disadvantage is that you will have to set the font size of the `li` elements. Unfortunately you can't set that size relative to the ul's parent.

Comment: Yes. Personally, I tend to have a rule like `p, li, span, td { font-size: 1rem; }` at the head of all my main stylesheets to get round this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue when using `display: inline-block` and having an extra line in your code. To fix the extra space just use `font-size:0;` on the parent `ul` element. You will then need to reset the font size to the value of your choice in this `li`.

https://jsfiddle.net/8vhqyxxr/

Answer (score 0):

It's the actual white space (line break in this case) between the `li` elements. It's because they are inline block elements.

If you remove the breaks, the spaces are gone:

https://jsfiddle.net/3sph9wpg/9/

There are other possibilities, like messing around with the font-size. A font-size 0 results in zero-width spaces, so you could set `font-size: 0` on the `ul`. But unfortunately, there is no way to properly 'restore' the font size of the li relative to the ul's parent, so you will have to give the li elements an explicit font size, which can be ugly.

Another solution, also not pretty, is putting the whitespace inside the tags, so it is ignored, like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/3sph9wpg/10/

A similar problem is often found when you want to display multiple images (also inline-block elements) on a single line, and I'm sure that you can find numerous solutions for that problem that also apply to yours, but most, if not all of them, will be hacky-ish solutions like the ones mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css attribute `letter-spacing` on the `::after` pseudo element itself to correct it like this:

```
ul {
  li {
    display: inline-block;

    &:after {
      content: "|";
      letter-spacing: -3px;
    }
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/Lz8z11yw/1/

Browser support for letter-spacing: http://caniuse.com/#search=letter-spacing

Comment: That works, if your space is `3px` wide. You might also set a negative margin to get a similar effect, or use something like `1ex`, which is a relative unit to the font-size, so the solution is less dependent on the actial font-size.

Comment: Yep and this way you can avoid some of the issues in the other answers.